# Debugger doesn't hit certain breakpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I'm working on a ASP.NET 5 Web API project on VS2019. I'm trying to set a breakpoint on the POST action (PostCustomerPayment) in the controller however, the breakpoint is never hit. I tried setting breakpoints in several other areas (such as the GET action and other controllers) and they work just fine. I've been trying to figure it out for hours and I even tried repairing visual but no luck. Any help would be really appreciated

Here is the code for the controller:

```
namespace IcartE1.Controllers.API
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]

    public class CustomerPaymentsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly ICipherService _cipherService;

        public CustomerPaymentsController(ApplicationDbContext context,ICipherService cipherService)
        {
            _context = context;
            _cipherService = cipherService;
        }

        // GET: api/CustomerPayments
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<CustomerPayment>>> GetCustomerPayment()
        {
            var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            var payments = await _context.CustomerPayment.Where(cp=> cp.CustomerId==userId).ToListAsync();
            foreach(var payment in payments)
            {
                payment.CardNumber = _cipherService.Decrypt(payment.CardNumber);
            }
            return payments;
        }

        // POST: api/CustomerPayments
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<CustomerPayment>> PostCustomerPayment([FromForm] CustomerPayment customerPayment)
        {
            customerPayment.CustomerId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                customerPayment.CardNumber = _cipherService.Encrypt(customerPayment.CardNumber);
                _context.CustomerPayment.Add(customerPayment);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return CreatedAtAction("GetCustomerPayment", new { id = customerPayment.Id }, customerPayment);
            }
            return ValidationProblem();
        }

        // DELETE: api/CustomerPayments/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteCustomerPayment(int id)
        {
            var customerPayment = await _context.CustomerPayment.FindAsync(id);
            if (customerPayment == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.CustomerPayment.Remove(customerPayment);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

        private bool CustomerPaymentExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.CustomerPayment.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: [Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9cfa.png)

The model in question

```
public class CustomerPayment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required,Display(Name ="Holder Name")]
        [RegularExpression(pattern: @"^[a-zA-Z ]+$", ErrorMessage = "Holder name can only contain letters.")]
        public string HolderName { get; set; }

        [Required,Display(Name ="Card Number")]
        [CreditCard]
        public string CardNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    }
```

EDIT 2: Because customerId was set as required the action is handled earlier so the request doesn't hit the controller at all, removing [Required] annotation tag from customerId fixed the problem

Comment: "the breakpoint is never hit" - what does happen? is the code being executed or you get an error message?

Comment: @YosiDahari code continues executing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `customerId` was set as required, the action is handled earlier in the pipeline so the request doesn't hit the controller at all. Removing the `[Required]` annotation tag from `customerId` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`PostCustomerPayment([FromForm] CustomerPayment customerPayment)`

I suspect it's how you are accessing the action. Since you're using [FromForm], your request should be like;

```
site.com/api/CustomerPaymentsController/PostCustomerPayment?PropertyName=Test
```

Try changing it to `[FromBody]` if you're trying to POST json body.

You could read more about model binding here; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#frombody-attribute

Comment: I send form-data in the body through Postman which is why I use [FromForm]. I suspected the same as you and changed it to [FromBody] earlier and tried sending a JSON body as you suggested but it resulted in the same thing

Comment: @OmarHossam will you include the model properties, and your postman request in the question

Comment: Included them now

Comment: @OmarHossam have you tried including `id=0` in your request?

Comment: just found the cause of the issue and I updated the question and provided an answer